# Angular, when the variable is mentioned in the url, the variable is not replaced with its value. Ex: ${username}

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am using @pathvariable in springboot to receive data from client. The variables are username, password and email.

I checked whether the values of variables are passed to the service. yes it is passed when I print that in the console log.

When the variables are assigned in the url as /${username)/${password)//${email), instead of getting the values of these variables, the ${username) is stored in the database instead of the username entered in the UI.

Verified with Postman, the values specified in the url is used to create the record in database, working fine.

The Rest Controller code and service code are attached:

```
Rest Controller 
_________________

@RestController
public class UserResource {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/user/{username}/{password}/{email}",
        method = RequestMethod.POST)

public ResponseEntity  newUserPost(@PathVariable("username") String username,
@PathVariable("password") String password,
@PathVariable("email") String email,
HttpServletResponse response)
throws Exception {

registerUser function in Service
________________________________

    registerUser(username: string, password: string, email: string) {
    let params = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;
 console.log(params);

    let url = 'http://localhost:8080/user/${username}/${password}/${email}'
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        });
      return this.http.post(url, {headers: headers, responseType : 'text'});
}
```

The values of variable needs to be sent to the spring boot.

Answer (score 2):

if should be wrapped around `` not single qoutes

```
let url = `http://localhost:8080/user/${username}/${password}/${email}`
```